# How to retrieve tweets from a week ago using Tweepy in API 3.9

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy,re,json,matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns,pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob
```

```
consumer_key = "key"
consumer_secret = "key"
access_key = "key"
secret_key = "key"
autenticacion = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
autenticacion.set_access_token(access_key, secret_key)
"""Variable donde voy a llamar a la API"""
api = tweepy.API(autenticacion, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

```
results = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='Panamá', tweet_mode="extended",lang="en",since='2020-11-12',until='2020-11-18').items(2000)
term = 'Panamá'
json_data = [r._json for r in results]
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data)
```

I'm trying to extract a thousand tweets from today's date, a week back, but all the tweets I extract are from today's date. How do I go about extracting tweets with dates from a week ago to today, evenly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API itself does not support an even distribution of results on a per-day basis across a week, so you would have to implement this yourself. The count parameter only supports a maximum of 100 results per page. At the moment, your code is basically asking for 100 Tweets looking back from now.

You could try the following:

- break down your 1000 results by 7 days (to make this easier, let's make it 100 per day, so 700 Tweets total)
- create a 7 pass loop around your second block of code, and for each iteration, search for 100 results, each time making the `since` and `until` values for the same day, so `'2020-11-12'` to `'2020-11-12'`, `'2020-11-13'` to `'2020-11-13'`, etc
- in each loop iteration, append your data into the dataframe

Also note that the line where you have `term = 'Panamá'` is apparently unused in the code above.